como hago para que se tenga que completar una respuesta mal hecha y no todo el formulario o opcionario de nuevo con Try y except
#yo quiero que si se completa mal una respuesta, esa pregunta se tenga que hacer de nuevo pero sin tener que repetir todo el cuestonario. Ej. Si la pregunta de los invitados esta mal respuesta, que se repita solo esa pregunta y no todo el cuestionario.
        while(True):
            try:
                evento.append(input("Añadir un titulo: "))
                año1=(int(input("ingresa el año del evento")))
                mes2=(int(input("ingresa el mes")))
                dia3=(int(input("ingresa el dia")))
                horario.append(date(year=año1, month=mes2 , day=dia3))
                hora= input("Escribi la hora en este formato(12:00): ")
                invitados.append (int(input("Añadir invitados(Si no queres añadir invitados apreta 0): ")))
                ubicacion.append(input("Añadi una ubicación"))
                break
                    
            except:
                print("Debes usar numeros en los espacios indicados")


Tendrías que ir evaluando cada pregunta a la vez:
while True:
    try:
        año1 = int(input("ingresa el año del evento: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Por favor, ingresa un número válido para el año.")

Esto, al momento de evaluar el input y ver que no es un INT, arrojaría el error.
Ahora, podemos repetir lo mismo para los similares y ahorrarnos algo de código:
while True:
    try:
        año = int(input("ingresa el año del evento: "))
        mes = int(input("ingresa el mes del evento 1-12: "))
        dia = int(input("ingresa el día del evento: "))
        fecha = date(año, mes, dia) # Validamos todas
        horario.append(fecha)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Fecha no válida. Por favor, ingresa valores correctos.")

Puedes hacer lo mismo para el resto de preguntas que vayas agregando.
Aunque creo que es mejor realizar algunas funciones acá.

Tal vez algo como esto te resulte util:
def evento():
    while( True ):
        try:
            evento.append( input( "Añadir un titulo: " ))
            año1 = ( int( getValor( "ingresa el año del evento" )))
            mes2 = ( int( getValor( "ingresa el mes" )))
            dia3 = ( int( getValor( "ingresa el dia" )))
            horario.append( date( yea r= año1, month = mes2 , day = dia3 ))
            hora = getValor( "Escribi la hora en este formato(12:00): " )
            invitados.append ( int( input( "Añadir invitados(Si no queres añadir invitados apreta 0: ")))
            ubicacion.append( input( "Añadi una ubicación" ))
            break
            
    except:
        print( "Debes usar numeros en los espacios indicados" )
        
def getValor( texto ):
    while( True ):
        valor = input( texto )
        if( texto == "Escribi la hora en este formato(12:00): " ):
            return comprueboHora( valor )
        else:
            return comprueboNumero( valor, texto )
            
        
def comprueboNumero( valor, texto ):
    try:
        dato = int( valor )
        if texto == "ingresa el año del evento":
           return True
        elif texto == "ingresa el mes":
           return True
        elif texto == "ingresa el dia":
           return True
    except:
        print( "Debes usar numeros en los espacios indicados" )
        return False

def comprueboHora( valor ):
    if valor == valor:
       return True
    else:
        print( "Debes ingresar la hora en el formato indicado" )
        return False


Nota que falta implementar la comprobacion en comprueboAño(), comprueboMes(), comprueboDia() y comprueboHora()
